# How to count the total number of instructions executed in an assembly program

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu, instructions, mars-simulator

What is the fastest way to calculate the total number of instructions executed by the CPU when executing a program written in assembly ?
For small programs can do this manually , but for larger programs ?
I write in assembly using Mars4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click *Tools* -> *Instruction Counter* -> *Connect to MIPS*. Then run your program.