# Does the MARS instruction counter work with Static or Dynamic Instructions?

Tags: assembly, mips, instruction-set, mars-simulator

I found [this thread regarding the instruction counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773840/how-to-count-the-total-number-of-instructions-executed-in-an-assembly-program), but wanted a bit more info on how the counter works within MARS4. Are the instructions displayed Static or Dynamic? If so, is there a way to find the other one? Thank you!

Comment: A static count is a compile-time concept.  A dynamic count is a runtime concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the *instructions* that are dynamic or static, it's the *count*.

A count of instructions *executed* is a dynamic instruction-count, and the Q&A you linked says that's what MARS's counter gives you.

A static instruction-count is just code-size: look at the binary window after assembling, and subtract the last - first addresses.  Instructions = bytes/4.  (Minus any padding for alignment if you don't want to count that, but often you do because what really matters is code footprint in the I-cache, and size to be loaded from disk.  An instruction that never runs is basically indistinguishable from padding for alignment.)

(So static I-count is pretty trivial, like line count of disassembly.
But the dynamic count depends on how the program runs; that's why it's useful to have a dynamic instruction counter in a simulator.)